# SQL self Inner JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, self-join

Employee table:

| id | name | salary | managerId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 70000 | 3 |
| 2 | Henry | 80000 | 4 |
| 3 | Sam | 60000 | Null |
| 4 | Max | 90000 | Null |

What  is the difference between below queries?

```
SELECT E.name as Employee
FROM Employee as E
INNER JOIN Employee as E2
ON E.id = E2.managerId
```

this one returns Sam, Max

```
SELECT E.name as Employee
FROM Employee as E
INNER JOIN Employee as E2
ON E.managerId = E2.id
```

this one returns Joe, Henry

Comment: The first one shows the managers, the second one shows the employees that have managers.

Comment: @Barmar while I agree .. I think this may be OP homework, and the real question is WHY `INNER JOIN` returns two separate result sets when the  `E.id = E2.managerId` is switched to `E.managerId = E2.id`

Comment: How are you stuck quoting & applying a definition & answering this yourself? Right now you're asking for yet another presentation of the language with a bespoke tutorial while giving no detail of your misconceptions/mistakes. Please give a [mre] & chopped at the 1st point you get an unexpected value say what you expected & why, justified by authoritative documentation. [ask] [Help] [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score -2):

```sql
SELECT E.name as Employee
  FROM Employee as E
  JOIN Employee as E2 ON E.id = E2.managerId
```

Results into

| E.id | E.name | E.salary | E.managerId | E2.id | E2.name | E2.salary | E2.managerId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Sam | 60000 | Null | 1 | Joe | 70000 | 3 |
| 4 | Max | 90000 | Null | 2 | Henry | 80000 | 4 |

Take only E.name from the result:

| E.name |
| --- |
| Sam |
| Max |

```sql
SELECT E.name as Employee
  FROM Employee as E
  JOIN Employee as E2 ON E.managerId = E2.id
```

Results into:

| E.id | E.name | E.salary | E.managerId | E2.id | E2.name | E2.salary | E2.managerId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 70000 | 3 | 3 | Sam | 60000 | Null |
| 2 | Henry | 80000 | 4 | 4 | Max | 90000 | Null |

Take only E.name:

| E.name |
| --- |
| Joe |
| Henry |

Comment: There is no new information here .. OP knows what the results are if you read the question ..

Comment: You haven't explained *why* this happens.